# Can Azure CDN endpoint names be reused?

Tags: azure-cdn

Why can't I reuse names from endpoints that have been previously deleted? For example, if I create an endpoint named "acme-cdn1", delete it, and try to create a new endpoint with the same name I get the following message: "Error, that endpoint name already exists." Is it necessary delete the entire CDN profile in order to reuse old endpoint names?

Comment: Apparently, no. (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/c8731187-2aa3-4fb3-a345-6b5e276d77b9/reuse-endpoint-names?forum=azurecdn)

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot.

CDN endpoint is reserved for sometime once created. This is to prevent other people create CDN endpoint right after you delete your endpoint and get your traffic due to CDN setup take 3 hours +.

For example, let's say I created a CDN endpoint called myendpoint.azureedge.net and I was using it to streaming my pictures. And I deleted myendpoint.azureedge.net. Suddenly, you created the endpoint called myendpoint.azureedge.net. When you visit the url, you can still see my pictures even you already set the different origin.

Such operation will not be completed for at least two hours. In this case your CDN endpoint is not usable and you will be billed on the traffic which is not acceptable.